# What does the fieldset validity mean?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, constraints

Here's the documentation: [HTMLFieldSetElement - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFieldSetElement).
I wonder what the `fieldset` validity mean. Does it mean the validity of all the `inputs`, for example, inside the `fieldset`? Then why doesn't the following work if you enter out-of-range values:

```js
var form = document.querySelector('form');

form.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var fieldsets = form.querySelectorAll('fieldset');
  for (var fieldset of fieldsets) {
    var output = fieldset.querySelector('output');
    if (fieldset.validity.valid) {
      output.value = 'Valid!';
    } else {
      output.value = 'Invalid!';
    }
  }
});
```

```css
input {
  width: 4em;
}

input:invalid {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
    <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
    <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
    <output></output>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
    <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
    <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
    <output></output>
  </fieldset>
  <button type="button">Validate</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://dev.w3.org/html5/pf-summary/forms.html#the-fieldset-element

> Constraint validation: fieldset elements are always barred from constraint validation.

https://dev.w3.org/html5/pf-summary/forms.html#barred-from-constraint-validation

> A listed form-associated element is a candidate for constraint validation unless a condition has barred the element from constraint validation. (For example, an element is barred from constraint validation if it is an output or fieldset element.)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFieldSetElement#Methods

> HTMLFieldSetElement.reportValidity()
>   Always returns true because  objects are never candidates for constraint validation.

You can do this:

```js
var form = document.querySelector('form');

form.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var fieldsets = form.querySelectorAll('fieldset');
  for (var fieldset of fieldsets) {
    var output = fieldset.querySelector('output');
    output.value = fieldset.querySelectorAll("input:invalid").length===0 ?  'Valid!' : 'Invalid!';
  }
});
```

```css
input {
  width: 4em;
}

input:invalid {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
    <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
    <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
    <output></output>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
    <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
    <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
    <output></output>
  </fieldset>
  <button type="button">Validate</button>
</form>
```

Or loop:

```js
var errors = {
  "valueMissing": "Missing",
  "typeMismatch": "Wrong type",
  "patternMismatch": "Wrong pattern",
  "tooLong": "Too long",
  "tooShort": "Too short",
  "rangeUnderflow": "< @",
  "rangeOverflow": "> @",
  "stepMismatch": "Step error",
  "badInput": "Not a number",
  "customError": ""
}
function getError(inp) {
  for (var val in inp.validity) {
    if (inp.validity[val]) {
      var error = errors[val];
      if (val === "rangeUnderflow") error = error.replace("@",inp.min)
      if (val === "rangeOverflow")  error = error.replace("@",inp.max)
      return error;
    }  
  }
}

var form = document.querySelector('form');

form.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var fieldsets = form.querySelectorAll('fieldset');
  for (var fieldset of fieldsets) {
    var output = fieldset.querySelector('output');
    output.value = 'Valid!';
    var inputs = fieldset.querySelectorAll("input");
    var errors = []
    for (var inp of inputs) {
      if (!inp.validity.valid) {
        errors.push(getError(inp));
      }  
    }
    if (errors.length) output.value=errors.join(" and ")
  }
});
```

```css
input {
  width: 4em;
}

input:invalid {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
    <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
    <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
    <output></output>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
    <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
    <input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100">
    <output></output>
  </fieldset>
  <button type="button">Validate</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I already know how to get the sample form to work.

Comment: See update. It turns out that <fieldset> objects are never candidates for constraint validation. It just inherits the htmlelement's validity object but does nothing with it

Comment: This is what I saw [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation#The_constraint_validation_API) for the first time.

Comment: Yes, and when you dig deeper: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFieldSetElement#Methods

Comment: Just wanna comment to say that this is super dumb. Wasted many hours trying to debug what was happening lol

Comment: The fieldset not performing validation as expected, your solution is awesome, I actually did something similar by chance